# Autocomplete feature in Redis 3.0

Tags: redis

I need to build an auto complete feature with the help of redis.I went through Antirez's article regarding this.However i dont need to give all the possible combinations of the given word to the user.For ex.
I need to provide,
1.The new york times
2.The bombay times
only
to the user when he type "t","th","The" and so on.
How do i acheive this using redis commands.

Comment: Your question is unclear, perhaps it would be good to include the link you are referring to. In any case, the commands you need to use are `ZADD` and `ZRANGEBYLEX`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with below link
https://www.cucumbertown.com/craft/autocomplete-using-redis-nginx-lua/

However how to deal with members having same score , i need those sorted with below priorities:
1.score
2.lexographically

example :

127.0.0.1:6379> zrange auto 0 -1 withscores
1) "the british times"
2) "0"
3) "the new york times"
4) "0"
5) "the sydney times"
6) "0"
7) "the bombay times"
8) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379>  zrangebylex auto (the "(the\xff"
1) "the british times"
2) "the new york times"
3) "the sydney times"
4) "the bombay times"

I want bombay times to be at 2 nd place and not fourth.How to do this ?